# Partition a list on python

Tags: python, list

The following code partitions a list in spaces of 5.

```
o_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
 
def partition(lst, size):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), size):
        yield lst[i :: size]

# size of each partition
n = 5

p_list = list(partition(o_list, n))

print("Original List: ")
print(o_list)
print("Partitioned List:")
print(p_list)
```

The following are the results:

```
Original List: 
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
Partitioned List:
[[10, 60, 110, 160], [60, 110, 160], [110, 160], [160]]
```

However I want the second array to be `[20, 70, 120, 170]` and the third and so on follow suit.

Comment: Should `n` be the target size of each partition? or the amount of elements to skip before taking the next? As your code is now, it is latter

Comment: `n` is the amount of elements to skip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the comma in the `range` function to a `//` operator:

```py
o_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
 
def partition(lst, size):
    for i in range(0, len(lst) // size):
        yield lst[i :: size]

# size of each partition
n = 5

p_list = list(partition(o_list, n))

print("Original List: ")
print(o_list)
print("Partitioned List:")
print(p_list)
```

This prints:

```
Original List: 
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
Partitioned List:
[[10, 60, 110, 160], [20, 70, 120, 170], [30, 80, 130, 180], [40, 90, 140, 190]]
```

Comment: Could I ask, cause this will be used for creating 100 arrays with 25 points each from a variable containing 2500 points. When I set `n` as 100, the `partition` creates 25 lists with 25 points and when I set `n` as 25 it creates 100 lists with 100 points. How can I create 100 lists with 25 points only? Does the variable with 2500 points need to be increased?

Comment: I think I managed by simply using `yield lst[i :: len(lst)//size]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
o_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]

[o_list[x::5] for x in range(len(o_list)//5)]

[[10, 60, 110, 160],
 [20, 70, 120, 170],
 [30, 80, 130, 180],
 [40, 90, 140, 190]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With division you can figure out how many slices can be produced, then simply produce those slices in a loop.

```
partition = lambda L, N: [L[n::N] for n in range(len(L)//N)]

print(partition(list(range(10, 201, 10)), 5))

#[[10, 60, 110, 160], [20, 70, 120, 170], [30, 80, 130, 180], [40, 90, 140, 190]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def partition(lst, size):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), size):
        yield lst[i:i + size]
```